# PHP Web services problem

Tags: php, web-services, wsh

i need to implement a web service using PHP , i tried WSO2/WSF PHP framework but it was every hard to install on Apache (XAMPP) ... followed many tutorials but i think because of a version problem it doesn't work

is there any frameworks such as WSO2/WSF which can be used to create a web service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of PHP frameworks that can be used to create webservices. I prefer to use cakePHP and send the output of my webservice in JSON format (very clean, compact).

Check out this basic tutorial
http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/07/json-output-with-cakephp/

Comment: Thanks but i was trying nuSoap :-)